# jQuery custom content scroller: remove mouse scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having trouble and was wondering if anyone could please help? I have incorporated a jQuery custom content scroller into my site (link:http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/). The plug-in is great and is everything that I need - however I was wondering if there was a way to prevent mouse scrolling when using this plug-in? So basically the user can only use the scroll bar as opposed to using the mouse scroll. Here is the code I have so far:

```html
<head>
  <!-- stylesheet for demo and examples -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
 <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->
 
 <!-- custom scrollbar stylesheet -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css">
</head>
<body>
<center>
 <table style="width:100%; height:auto; max-width:1200px; border-bottom:1px solid #c4c4c4;">
  <tr>
   <td>
    title 1
   </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;">
    title 2
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="2">
    
    <br />
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    <div id="demo" style="padding-left:0x;">

   
   <!-- content -->
   <div id="content-1" class="content horizontal-images" style="background-color:white; padding:0px; height:120px;">
    <ul>
     <li><img style="height:70px; width:auto; padding-right:13px; background-color:white;" src="tester.png" /></li>
     <li><img style="height:70px; width:auto; padding-right:13px; background-color:white;" src="tester.png" /></li>
     <li><img style="height:70px; width:auto; padding-right:13px; background-color:white;" src="tester.png" /></li>
     <li><img style="height:70px; width:auto; padding-right:13px; background-color:white;" src="tester.png" /></li>
     <li><img style="height:70px; width:auto; padding-right:13px; background-color:white;" src="tester.png" /></li>
     <li><img style="height:70px; width:auto; padding-right:13px; background-color:white;" src="tester.png" /></li>
     <li><img style="height:70px; width:auto; padding-right:13px; background-color:white;" src="tester.png" /></li>
     <li><img style="height:70px; width:auto; padding-right:13px; background-color:white;" src="tester.png" /></li>
     <li><img style="height:70px; width:auto; padding-right:13px; background-color:white;" src="tester.png" /></li>
     <li><img style="height:70px; width:auto; padding-right:13px; background-color:white;" src="tester.png" /></li>
     <li><img style="height:70px; width:auto; padding-right:13px; background-color:white;" src="tester.png" /></li>
     <li><img style="height:70px; width:auto; padding-right:13px; background-color:white;" src="tester.png" /></li>
     <li><img style="height:70px; width:auto; padding-right:13px; background-color:white;" src="tester.png" /></li>
     <li><img style="height:70px; width:auto; padding-right:13px; background-color:white;" src="tester.png" /></li>
     <li><img style="height:70px; width:auto; padding-right:13px; background-color:white;" src="tester.png" /></li>
     
   </div>

 </div>
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
   </td>
  </tr>
  
 </table>
</center>
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 <!-- Google CDN jQuery with fallback to local -->
 <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../js/minified/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
 
 <!-- custom scrollbar plugin -->
 <script src="jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
 
 <script>
  (function($){
   $(window).load(function(){
    
    /* 
    get snap amount programmatically or just set it directly (e.g. "273") 
    in this example, the snap amount is list item's (li) outer-width (width+margins)
    */
    var amount=Math.max.apply(Math,$("#content-1 li").map(function(){return $(this).outerWidth(true);}).get());
    
    $("#content-1").mCustomScrollbar({
     axis:"x",
     theme:"inset",
     advanced:{
      autoExpandHorizontalScroll:true
     },
     scrollButtons:{
      enable:true,
      scrollType:"stepped"
     },
     keyboard:{scrollType:"stepped"},
     snapAmount:amount,
     mouseWheel:{scrollAmount:amount}
    });
    
   });
  })(jQuery);
  
  
  
  
  
 </script>
 </body>
```

Thanks - any help is highly appreciated :)

Comment: According to the documentation, you simply set `mouseWheel` to `false`. Have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks @Stef - this worked great

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#content-1").mCustomScrollbar({enable: false});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @木士羽 - where about in my code should I implement this?

Comment: Could you explain why this answer should fix the problem?